# How to check current user session using AWS Amplify?

Tags: swift, aws-amplify

I am following along with AWS Amplify documentation and the example code given to check the current auth session is

```
 func fetchCurrentAuthSession() {
    _ = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let session):
            print("Is user signed in - \(session.isSignedIn)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Fetch session failed with error \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

after calling this func in a viewDidLoad I get this error **Thread 1: Fatal error: Authentication category is not configured. Call Amplify.configure() before using any methods on the category.** So I then changed the code to this

```
      func fetchCurrentAuthSession() {
            do {
                try Amplify.configure()
            _ = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let session):
                    print("Is user signed in - \(session.isSignedIn)")
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Fetch session failed with error \(error)")
                }
            }
        }catch{

        }

    }
```

It runs with no errors but the authSession is not printed. 
What is the proper way to fix this? here is the link to their docs https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/ios#check-the-current-auth-session

Here is my ***awsconfiguration.json***

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify/cli",
    "Version": "0.1.0",
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "removed",
                "Region": "removed"
            }
        }
    },
    "CognitoUserPool": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "removed",
            "AppClientId": "removed",
            "AppClientSecret": "removed",
            "Region": "removed"
        }
    },
    "FacebookSignIn": {
        "AppId": "removed",
        "Permissions": "public_profile"
    },
    "Auth": {
        "Default": {
            "authenticationFlowType": "USER_SRP_AUTH"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ***amplifyconfiguration.json***

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
    "Version": "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common error associated with older versions of the Amplify CLI.

1.Update it in the terminal using `npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli` .

2.Once that is done remove Amplify Auth from the project directory by `amplify remove auth`.

3.Enter `amplify push` to configure changes within your backend.

4.Now you can successfully add auth back to your project `amplify add auth`

5.Enter `amplify push` to configure changes within your backend.

6.Now run your project and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the Amplify and AmplifyPlugin packages in the AppDelegate.swift in your root folder.

```
import UIKit
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins
```

Then add the following function

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     do {
            try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            try Amplify.configure()
            print("Amplify configured with auth plugin")
        } catch {
            print("An error occurred setting up Amplify: \(error)")
        }
    return true
}
```

And most important,

> you must check whether the **user's email is confirmed ?**.

If the email is not confirmed, then isSignedIn will always be false. You can check this for the particular emailId in the userPool

Comment: I forgot to mention I have already added that code to my app delegate when I was following along with the documentation. I have not registered users yet I just wanted to see the fetchCurrentAuthSession func print false since no user is signed in.

Answer (score 1):

Your modified fetchCurrentAuthSession is hitting your catch block but you aren't doing anything to show the error.
If you add something like 
    print("Inside catch: (error)") 
inside the catch you should see the error which will likely be that you are calling Amplify.configure() again.
What is in your awsconfiguration.json and amplifyconfiguration.json files (mask out your poolId, appClientID and region before posting)?

Comment: I have edited my question to show my awsconfiguration.json and amplifyconfiguration.json files.